# Dynamicly creating rows with Javascript then sending to Flask. No information being transfered

Tags: javascript, python, flask, input

My issue is that my dynamically created rows ( by javascript) are not being sent to my back end python function.

I have created a script which creates a table row with 7 columns, in each column is a html input. These inputs will be used by the user to input information about products. ( serial number / part number etc...)

```
function Add_row() {
     var tbl = document.getElementById('sct_components_table');
     var iteration = tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length;
     newRow = tbl.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);
     var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
     newCell.classList.add("sct_components_input")
     newCell.innerHTML = '0' + iteration;

     var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
     newCell1.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el = document.createElement('input');
     el.type = 'text';
     el.name = 'quantity';
     el.value = '';
     newCell1.appendChild(el);

     var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
     newCell2.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el2 = document.createElement('input');
     el2.type = 'text';
     el2.name = 'part_number';
     newCell2.appendChild(el2);

     var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(3);
     newCell3.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el3 = document.createElement('input');
     el3.type = 'text';
     el3.name = 'serial_number';
     newCell3.appendChild(el3);

     var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
     newCell4.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el4 = document.createElement('textarea');
     el4.type = 'text';
     el4.name = 'description';
     newCell4.appendChild(el4);

     var newCell5 = newRow.insertCell(5);
     newCell5.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el5 = document.createElement('input');
     el5.type = 'text';
     el5.name = 'installed_by_cm';
     newCell5.appendChild(el5);

     var newCell6 = newRow.insertCell(6);
     newCell6.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el6 = document.createElement('input');
     el6.type = 'text';
     el6.name = 'installed_after_cm';
     newCell6.appendChild(el6);

     var newCell7 = newRow.insertCell(7);
     newCell7.classList.add("sct_components_input");
     var el7 = document.createElement('textarea');
     el7.type = 'text';
     el7.name = 'notes';
     newCell7.appendChild(el7);
 }
```

The inputs are collected by a flask framework with the following code

```
temp_multi_quantity = request.form.getlist('quantity')
temp_multi_part_number = request.form.getlist('part_number')
temp_multi_serial_number = request.form.getlist('serial_number')
temp_multi_description = request.form.getlist('description')
temp_multi_installed_by_cm = request.form.getlist('installed_by_cm')
temp_multi_installed_after_cm = request.form.getlist('installed_after_cm')
temp_multi_notes = request.form.getlist('notes')
```

If I manually create the table rows on the html page they are uploaded successfully. It is only the 'Javascript Rows' which are ignored.

This code mimics an example found at: http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tablebasics5.html 
This example is old and uses php not python, so that could be where I have got confused, but I used wireshark on the page and it appeared to be submitting.

If anyone could shed some light as to what concept I have misunderstood / the mistake I have made, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify in the browser console that the newly created field actually have the right names and are part of the form?

Comment: I can confirm that they do appear in the Developer tool and have the exact same 'name' tag as rows I created by hand. As for being part of the form; using Wireshark on my own page, I did not see the new rows. So my guess is that they are not being sent to the form. But that is just a guess.